# Searchbar fetching data problem Next js 13 in ec2 ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, next.js, amazon-ec2, next.js13

**Nextjs 13 Code**

```
"use client"
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Styles from "./page.module.css"


import { LuSearchX } from "react-icons/lu";

const Search = () => {
    const q = useSearchParams().get("q") || "";
    const page = useSearchParams().get("page") || 1;
  
    
  
  const [searchApi, setSearchApi] = useState({});


  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        if (!q || !page) return; // Null checks
        const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/search?q=${q}&page=${page}`,
        {
          cache:"no-cache"
        });
        const data = await res.json();
        setSearchApi(data.response);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    }

    fetchData();
  }, [q, page]);

  const zeroResult = () =>{
    if(searchApi.results && searchApi.results.length == 0)
    {
   
      return true;
    
    }
    
  }
  return (
    <div className={Styles.searchWithFooter}>
    <div className={Styles.searchDiv}>
      {zeroResult()  && <div className={Styles.notFound}> <LuSearchX className={Styles.icon}/> No Result Found</div>}
      {searchApi.results && searchApi.results.map((val, ind) => (
        <a key={ind} href={val.link} className={Styles.boxContainer}>
          <div>
            <h2>{val.title}</h2>`your text`
            <div className={Styles.location}>{val.loc}</div>
          {val.des &&  <p className={Styles.des}>{val.des}</p> }
          </div>
        </a>
      ))}
    </div>
    </div>
  );
};



export default Search
```

- This is working in localhost but not working in ec2 ubuntu server and there is separate server for backend and separate server for frontend.
- And also tell us what should be allowed in the security group of amazon ec2.
- And also tell us how to configure .env in Ubuntu Server.